# Can't connect to localhost after Avast antivirus latest update

Tags: windows, localhost, antivirus

After latest update of Avast cant load localhost websites (browser loader keeps spinning)

- Firewall for port 80 is ok
- 127.0.0.1 pings ok
- I disabling Avast, all works fine
- Previous versions of Avast were fine
- I use IIS 7 on Win7 Ultimate Service pack 1
- Avast update version: 2014.9.0.2006
- All sites are on PHP, MYSQL

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try 127.0.0.1 in browser
instead of localhost. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just re-installed Avast!internet security, and it all worked. Probably during 3 years of subscription something somewhere somehow went wrong. Sometimes happens :)